# Script defined in rootLayout is not getting added for client page in NEXTJS13

Tags: next.js13

I am trying to add Google Tag Manager to my nextJS code and the script is not getting added to client pages but getting added other pages. I have added this in my rootlayout

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `{code for google tag manager}` />
```